# Unit testing a parallel Java program

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I'm trying to write a JUnit test.  My problem is that my threads can't see the object I have created in the sequential bit of code (code before starting the threads).

```
public class MyTest implements Runnable {

    private MyClass mc;

    /**
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    @Test
    public void parallelTest() throws InterruptedException {
        this.mc = new MyClass();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyTest());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyTest());
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        // TODO the test
    }

    public void run() {
       if(mc != null) {
          System.out.println("ph not null");
       } else {
          System.out.println("ph null"); // THIS CODE GETS EXECUTED
       }
       // some code
    }
}
```

See the comment in the `run` method above.  My object is null but I want both threads to be able to access the `MyClass` object.  How come they see null?  I tried using a constructor but I think the interface prevented me from passing a parameter to the constructor.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you `join`ing before `start`ing?

Comment: *I'm trying to write a JUnit test for my unit test*: This is going too far ;-)

Comment: Your problem is deeper: you do not know what an *object* and what `new` does - and this is quite a problem for a Java programmer. If I were you, I would stay away from threads and testing and for some time - just stick to some basic stuff (writing classes, making instances and objects). If you manage to fix your code (by writing `this` instead of `new MyTest()`) in the two lines instantiating threads, you will run into deeper problems, as writing correct programs using multiple threads, and testing them, is much, much, much, much harder than that.

Comment: What are your reasons for testing a unit test and for using threads to do so?

Comment: @JB Nizet: LOL!  Question edited.

Comment: @MonadNewb See question edit.. it was a typo sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize the `.mc` filed of `this` but then you create two new instances of `MyTest` (in which `.mc` is not initialized, that is: it is `null`) and pass these instances to your threads.

The solution is therefore quite simple: pass `this` to the threads.

[EDIT]

Also, I had to switch the order of the .start() and the .join() calls - waiting for a thread to finish (i.e., `join`) is meaningful only if the thread has been previously started.

```
package p1;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest implements Runnable {

  private MyClass mc;

  /**
   * @throws InterruptedException
   */
  @Test
  public void parallelTest() throws InterruptedException {
      this.mc = new MyClass();
      Thread thread1 = new Thread(this);
      Thread thread2 = new Thread(this);
      thread1.start();
      thread2.start();
      thread1.join();
      thread2.join();
  }

  public void run() {
     if(mc != null) {
        System.out.println("ph not null");
     } else {
        System.out.println("ph null"); // THIS CODE GETS EXECUTED
     }
     // some code
  }
}
```

When I run it I get this output:

```
ph not null
ph not null
```

Comment: Tried this but then I get `Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor`

Comment: I just tried running the code and got "ph not null" as output. I am updating the answer again with exactly the same code that works for me .

Comment: Which version for JUnit are you using (if it matters?).  I found a solution (see the one I posted) but your solution would be simpler if I could get it working.  I'm using JUnit 4.

Comment: Yes. With this solution you cannot have a constructor that takes argument. You're adding a constructor that takes a parameter made JUnit produce the `Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor` message. Once you go back to no construcotr or a single zero-arg constructor JUnit will stop complaining.

Answer (score 5):

Each runnable instance is created using `new MyTest()`. And the MyTest class doesn't have any constructor initializing the field `private MyClass mc;`. So it has its default value: null.

Each object has *its own* instance fields. That's a basic principle of OO.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out :).  I'll give some +1s because there were some further problems I had:

1. @Jeffrey: Yes, `start` and `join` were the wrong way round
2. @JB Nizet: Thanks.. I had a crazy typo in my question (edited question)

@Itay Maman had the same idea as me but it didn't work - JUnit wouldn't let me pass a parameter into its constructor.

Solution was not to use a constructor but use @BeforeClass annotation and an `init` method to instantiate a `MyClass`.

```
public class MyTest implements Runnable {

    private static MyClass mc;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        mc = new MyClass();
    }

    @Test
    public void parallelTest() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyTest());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyTest());
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
        // my assertion about mc object goes here
    }

    public void run() {
        // code to test
    }
}
```

This unit test still doesn't test the code perfectly because the execution path is non-deterministic so it could sometimes pass and sometimes fail.  Perhaps I will add some finer grain tests too.